# How to validate user input in Android?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a simple EditText where a user can insert three values separated by commas. For instance, I can have the following template:

```
value1, value2, value3
```

where value1, value2 are of double type and value3 is integer.

How can I validate that the user has entered a text according to this template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex [`Matcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

```
final String DOUBLE = "\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?";
final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(DOUBLE + ", " + DOUBLE + ", \\d+");
Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(textView.getText().toString());
if (!matcher.matches()) {
    // invalid input
}
```

Comment: Don't foreget to use the listener to catch the text changed event. [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)]

Comment: I do not know why, but there should be added one correction: 
    final String DOUBLE = "\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?";
    final Pattern Pattern = Pattern.compile(DOUBLE + ", " + DOUBLE + ", \\d+");
Can you correct and I'll accept the answer?

Comment: @Yury Silly me, you're right. In a java String literal, to get a black-slash, we need to escape it. So we need two back-slashes. Corrected my answer.

Comment: @Dheeraj Do not worry ) I think it was a nice training how I had understood the topic! Thanks!

Comment: @Yury To be more flexible, you can allow multiple spaces after the comma using `, *` for the separator. Also, leading & trailing spaces can be allowed by trimming the input: `textView.getText().toString().trim()`.